# Google Translate 403 Error

Tags: android, google-translate

I'm trying to create a **release version of an Android App using [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)**, but keep getting the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
  {
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "usageLimits",
      "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
      "reason" : "ipRefererBlocked",
      "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
    } ],
    "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
}
```

**It was working perfectly in Debug with a server key**. I've created an API key and an OAuth 2.0 client ID.

I use the following code to get a request (using [google's translate library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/)):

```
    // init
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleClientRequestInitializer googleClientRequestInitializer = new TranslateRequestInitializer(key);

    Translate.Builder translateBuilder = new Translate.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
    translateBuilder.setApplicationName(applicationName);
    translateBuilder.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(googleClientRequestInitializer);

    // Build the translator
    Translate translate = translateBuilder.build();

    // Create a list of the text to translate
    List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    text.add("Hello");

    // Translate text
    Translate.Translations.List list = translate.translations().list(text, targetLanguage);
    list.setFormat("text");

    TranslationsListResponse translateResponse = list.execute();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you generate a token?

Comment: No, I am just using a key.